# Non-natives using strong verbs as they were weak: would this compromise understanding?

Tags: verb, irregular-verb, evolution

Forgetting for a moment about the stated fact that language evolves, would Germans be annoyed if a strong verb was used as it were weak (that is, with the common -te pattern in the past tense and the ge- prefix in the past participle)?

Moreover, would this usage affect comprehension of what the person is saying, and to which level?

As an example, imagine that I say

> Gestern gehte ich ins Kino.

instead of

> Gestern ging ich ins Kino.

This is something that in English happens all the time, with no particular comprehension problems, does the same stand for German?

Comment: It wouldn't affect comprehension, but, being myself German, I think it is safe to say that many Germans tend to patronize people making this kind of mistake and, what's even worse, instead of giving corrective feedback, they sometimes use the same incorrect forms, believing to make themselves more understandable.

Comment: @bouscher: you mean things like `Du nix verstehen? Aber ich sprechen nix mehr schnell jetzt.`, right? Yes, that's terrible.

Comment: _something that in English happens all the time_ You sure? "Mom! Mom! Joey hurted me!" Okay, a pre-schooler can get away with it. Everybody else, though...

Comment: @EugeneSeidel Well, yes. It's something I'm doing scientific research on so I still don't have a precise answer (as for now). In any case, this is something that may happen to non-natives for verbs they don't know as well as to an ordinary native for a verb they've never (or scarcely) heard in their life. I wouldn't relate this to kids.

Comment: @martina: What is still not precise enough?

Comment: @falkb a lot of things, namely when and how the regularization of verbs happen in a language, whether the contribution of non-natives is fundamental...

Comment: @martina: not sure what you mean with "regularization of verbs" and where you wanna go to but a language never contributes the non-natives and there is no acceptance of wrong usage, maybe except rare changes like "Sinn machen" which is influenced by AE, and that is not to attract the non-natives.

Comment: @falkb talking about English, non-natives are contributing a lot, because they are probably more than the natives, considering that it is now the new lingua franca of the world. As for "wrong" or "right" usage, this is just something that evolves through time. But this is becoming a whole new question, about Linguistics in general.

Comment: I think non-natives can extend a language with words for things not already known by the natives, but it's not possible to change the very basics without fundamental social changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Germans would not be annoyed but amused. It sounds funny and reminds of toddler's typical mistakes. And there won't be a comprehension problem.

But if those mistakes still happen after you've lived in Germany for a year, people would start to wonder why you're not able to get it finally...

Comment: although from time to time I also fall in the trap to say 'teached', probably, because of 'reached', an -ed suffix seems to be logical ;)

Comment: I even know people who sometimes do that particular kind of mistake intentionally. For fun only, of course.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%:german.stackexchange.com+"teached" ;)

Comment: @PeterHorvath: you're right, the year was meant for the strong verbs only